# DateTimeParseException while using java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

Tags: java, scala, datetime, datetime-format

I am new to both stack overflow and programming. I am trying to use Java 8's to find the time difference between a TimeStamp value and Current Time Stamp Value.

Following is my code snippet of my Scala code:

```
println(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(Instant.parse("1534274986"), Instant.now()))
```

It works fine until I have a test case where the epoch to Human DateTime comes down to `08/14/18 19:06:17`. In that case, I get an error as:

```
Execution exception[[DateTimeParseException: Text '08/14/18 19:06:17' could not be parsed at index 0]]
```

Please help me understand why I am getting such an error. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the whole error message with the complete stack trace. The code snippet and the error message are unrelated.

Comment: provide more details about error.

Comment: I suppose that `08/14/18 19:06:17` means August 14, 2018 at 19:06:17 (7:06:17 PM). But in which time zone? Your own? UTC? If we don’t know, we cannot convert it to a timestamp ( `Instant`, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.parse()` method of `LocalDateTime` is rather limited by default. That's why you run into that error posted above. But you can solve this problem by designing and applying your own particular formatter using a FormatterBuilder in between:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendPattern("MM/dd/yy[ HH:mm:ss]")
  .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
  .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
  .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
  .toFormatter();

LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("08/14/18 19:06:17", formatter);
LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse("08/14/18 19:08:19", formatter);

System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(localDateTime1, localDateTime2));

// Result: 122000 ms
```

---

You can compare the formatted time to the current local time as well:

```
    LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(localDateTime1, currentDateTime));
```

---

And if you prefer to work with `Instant` you can easily create your own out of the `LocalDateTime` instances you parsed above:

```
    import java.time.*;

    LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("US/Eastern");
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(currentDateTime, zoneId);
    Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: But can I get time difference of a given Date Time with the Current Date Time? I need it with the current Date Time of Chicago @Lynx

Comment: Sure. Please have a look at my post. I extended it.